# Android Studio: Imported Figma UI Package via Relay Plugin, but UI Package Not Visible in Android View

Tags: android, relayjs, figma

I am facing an issue after importing a Figma UI package into Android Studio using the Google Relay plugin. The UI package seems to have been successfully imported, but it is not visible in the Android view within my project.

Figma URL: https://www.figma.com/file/Mn5tHa989dhFfufZ31RIX5/Untitled?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=EZDSPeJusbdvgb8k-1

Plugin Version:  Relay plugin: 0.3.10-hotfix

Steps Taken:
The pigma file was copied and imported into android studio through the Relay plugin.

Error/Issue Encountered:
I expected that a ui package would be created in Android View. It wasn't visible.

Additional Information:
However, the actual file contains the ui package.

It worked fine with the figma file and Android project provided by Android Developer, but it does not work properly with the figma file I created and the Android project I created.

To try the problem, I deleted the ui package that is not visible in the Android view but exists when entering the actual path and tried again.
Also, click Reload from Disk in the top folder in the project view. I tried it too, but there was no change.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your build.gradle(app) the following sourceSets:

```
android {
...
sourceSets {
        main {
            assets {
                srcDir('src/main/ui-packages')
            }
        }
    }

...

 defaultConfig {
..
```

You should see the files in the Android Studio.
Also, try to switch to "Project" view in the left pane.